# Problems executing node.js script from java Application

Tags: java, node.js

When I try to execute my node.js script from a java class I get the following error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node events.js": error=2, No such file or directory

here is my code can someone tell me what am I missing here?

```
public class NodeInitializer {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SpringLauncher.class);    
    private Process nodeProcess;
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder;

    public void start(){
        try {
            processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("node events.js");
            nodeProcess = processBuilder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getCause(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
List<String> commands = new LinkedList<String>();
commands.add("node");
commands.add("event.js");

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
processBuilder.start();
```

The [javadoc for ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.util.List%29) states

> a command, a list of strings which signifies the external program file
>   to be invoked and its arguments, if any. Which string lists represent
>   a valid operating system command is system-dependent. For example, it
>   is common for each conceptual argument to be an element in this list,
>   but there are operating systems where programs are expected to
>   tokenize command line strings themselves - on such a system a Java
>   implementation might require commands to contain exactly two elements.

In my experience, most OS's require you to tokenize the elements in the command you want to execute, so `[node] (the command/program) [events.js] (the argument)` as two elements in a list.

You are getting

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node events.js": error=2, No such file or directory
```

because java, through the OS, is trying to execute "node events.js" as a program, not as a program and its argument.

Comment: I edited and used the lis of arguments as you stated but what a get now is java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory and its on my system Path, do I have to set the variable?

Comment: @B.TIger try to put the full path of the node.. for ie: c:\\nodejs\node

Comment: yes it worked from the timeline The JVM wasn't Identifying my variables so I set the path for the script and the node program on a properties file that can be altered after implementation if needed thanks